# Change text of a label in the tableview section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an expandable tableview with custom headers. I need to change a text of a label in the header when the table is expanding. I used below code for this.

```
func toggleSection(header: SuperHeaderDelegate, section: Int) {
        sections[section].expanded = !sections[section].expanded

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.reloadSections([section], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        if let head = header as? SavingAccountHeaderView {
            head.accNoLabel.text = "HIIIIIII"
        }
        else { print("NOPE") }

    }
```

When I use this code it changes the **accNoLabel** text to new text and change it back to the old text again.

I have tried the `tableView.reloadData()` instead of the `tableView.reloadSections()`, then the code worked fine. The **accNoLabel** didn't change back to its old text. But I really need to use the `tableView.reloadSections()` to use the animation.
So could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest you to use a variable(string) for setting accNoLabel value, that will have latest value according to your condition. even if your table header is dequeued, text will be updated according to variable.

Comment: @pawan thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you should check:

1. Is your 'expanded' toggle happening at the right place (and time)?
2. reloadSections() is an asynchronous function. So you can't expect your text to be updated 'after' the updates have been completed.

I would suggest toggling your label's text inside the viewForHeader function, because at this point you can be sure that the reloadSections() method is being called and the section's state has already been updated.

Comment: changing the text in the viewForHeader function worked. Thanks for your help.